# How to call a function in a Twig file

Tags: 8, theming

Let's say I create a function in a module file:

```
function _get_test() {
  return 'test';
}
```

How can I call this in any Twig file? For example `*.html.twig`, `page.html.twig`, `node.html.twig` etc.

OR

How can I pass a variable from PHP to Twig and display in any Twig file. 
For example `*.html.twig`, `page.html.twig`, `node.html.twig` etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can define your own custom Twig functions in a custom module (but not in a theme). To find an example for how to do this, see this example in [`core/modules/system/tests/modules/twig_extension_test/src/TwigExtension/TestExtension.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.5/core/modules/system/tests/modules/twig_extension_test/src/TwigExtension/TestExtension.php).

---

Also see this blog post: [Create Twig extensions for Drupal 8](https://www.openaccess.fr/la-veille-du-web/create-twig-extension-drupal-8).

> In this example, we will build an extension to display a Drupal block
>   directly in a Twig template:
>
> ```
> {{ display_block('my_block_id') }}
> ```
>
> **src/MyTwigExtension.php**
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace Drupal\MyTwigModule;
>
> /**
>  * Class DefaultService.
>  *
>  * @package Drupal\MyTwigModule
>  */
> class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    * This function must return the name of the extension. It must be unique.
>    */
>   public function getName() {
>     return 'block_display';
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * In this function we can declare the extension function
>    */
>   public function getFunctions() {
>     return array(
>       new \Twig_SimpleFunction('display_block', 
>         array($this, 'display_block'),
>         array('is_safe' => array('html')
>       )),
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * The php function to load a given block
>    */
>   public function display_block($block_id) {
>     $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
>     return \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> **src/MyTwigModule.services.yml**
>
> ```
> services:
>   MyTwigModule.twig.MyTwigExtension:
>     class: Drupal\MyTwigModule\MyTwigExtension
>     tags:
>       - { name: twig.extension }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You do not call PHP functions in Twig. You can either create a custom Twig extension (see answer from leymannx) or use the global preprocess

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess(array &$variables, $hook) {
  //this is a global hook, its variables are available in any template file
  $variables['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

`{{ foo }}` will then render `bar`, but this global preprocess might run into caching problems though

Comment: It should better be [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to target a specific template.

Comment: @leymannx I'm explicitly using the one without _HOOK suffix as *global* preprocess, the ones with a specfic _HOOK suffix aren't global